# Adding a product to cart on Supreme via POST requests in Python - Request not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, python-requests, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to make a bot in Python that can add a product to my cart on Supreme upon detection. I want this to be efficient, and when I try to use HTTP post requests to get the job done, I receive response code 200 (OK) but the product isn't added in my basket.

I have tried this with both the Python requests module and the selenium requests module. The code is below:

```
post_headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.132 Safari/537.36', 'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
post_data = {"utf-8": "%E2%9C%93", 's': size_id, 'st': style_id, "X-CSRF-Token": csrf, "commit": "add to cart"}
url = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/{productid}/add".format(productid=id)
add_to_cart = session.post(url, headers=post_headers, data=post_data)
```

The response for `add_to_cart` is the HTTP code 200 (OK) but when I run `print(add_to_cart.text)`, I expect to see the product I added, however I just see `[]` (mobile user agent) or the supreme homepage html (desktop user agent), and figure out that there is nothing in the basket. I have also tried using a mobile user agent to get it working (json), and have also failed.

When I try to use selenium requests, I am using Google Chrome (otherwise I am using custom user agents).

I would appreciate any suggestion or way to fix this and be able to add products to my basket via HTTP POST requests.

Comment: that question is unclear, are you currently logged in with your code ? yes / no ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to see what you get in the response, you can also use `.content`:

```
add_to_cart = session.post(url, headers=post_headers, data=post_data)
print(add_to_cart.content)
```

From what I see being returned in that content, only `var h = {"76049":1,"cookie":"1 item--76049,26482"}` can be helpful to verify it was added.

Per what I see on that site, in order to get the full contents of the cart, you should also do another API call, GET on `https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/cart` with your headers.

Hopefully, this is helpful. Good luck!

Comment: The .content has helped me, and now I end up at a 404 page. Before I was receiving response 200. This is weird, but thanks! I still end up with `[]` as the response

Comment: Great @timb123! Good luck! feel free to upvote or select the answer if it is helpful :)

Comment: 404 is strange, is the product still there? what is the URL?

Comment: The 404 error is now gone, but I still end up with `[]` as the response. When I use Chrome's Inspect Element Tool to see the response of this post request, I get some json

Answer (score 0):

Why are you expecting to see your cart in the response to that POST? I know it seems logical that it perhaps would, but many websites are built in strange and mysterious ways.

Are you using the Chrome Developer Tools? If you look in the Network tab for a request to add something to the cart, you'll see under the response tab you just get a load of JavaScript back. However, if you look under the response cookies, you'll see something like this:

> cart  1+item--62197%2C28449

Which looks like the product IDs for whats in the cart, is in a Cookie. You could then look for that in your response by calling:

```
add_to_cart.cookies["cart"]
```

Alternatively, you could do a GET on:

> https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/cart

but you would then need to parse the HTML you get back.. probably easier to check the Cookies.

Comment: I am expecting to see a sort of cart response in my POST request because many other programmers who used the same or similar lines of code did get a response. I'll take a look at your suggestions to see if they help. I posted this because I thought there was something missing in my code. Maybe Supreme changed their site I don't know